# Batch file user account infos using findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr, net-use

I want to write a batch file that saves specific user account information's by using the windows command "net user account /domain". Problem is when I use the findstr the output is not written into the file:

```
set userlist = user1 user2 user3
for %x in (userlist) do (
net user %x /domain | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"  > D:\userInfoList.txt
)
```

This is just an example. At the end I want for every user an entry like this but with the actual informations.
username; lastLogin; nextPasswortChange etc.
How can I build such an output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Do not put spaces around the `=` in the `set` command line as they become part of the variable mane and value otherwise. 2. read variables like `%userlist%`. 3. Use `%%x` in the `for` loop as `%x` works only in case you are executing it in command prompt (`cmd`) directly.

Comment: One more thing to change:
Your code will only save the last value because it will overwrite each time through the loop. Typically I do something like this prior to the FOR loop.
    set "OutFile=D:\userInfoList.txt"
    if exist "%OutFile%" del /q "%OutFile%"

Then use 
>>"%OutFile%" 
instead of  
> D:\userInfoList.txt. This also has the advantage that it gets rid of the output from the previous run if you run it twice.